# Displaying proper malayalam text on PDF using Go lang gopdf

Tags: go, pdf, pdf-generation

I am trying to generate a PDF document with Malayalam text.

For this I am using the go pdf library https://github.com/signintech/gopdf

The issue is that the malayalam text is not displayed properly.

Good Text

[image]

Obtained Text from gopdf (Improper Text)

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix the issue ?

The font used is https://smc.org.in/downloads/fonts/meera/Meera-Regular.ttf

Below is the code used

```
package main
import (
    "log"
    "github.com/signintech/gopdf"
)

func main() {

    pdf := gopdf.GoPdf{}
    pdf.Start(gopdf.Config{ PageSize: *gopdf.PageSizeA4 })  
    pdf.AddPage()
    err := pdf.AddTTFFont("Meera-Regular", "Meera-Regular.ttf")
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err.Error())
        return
    }

    err = pdf.SetFont("Meera-Regular", "", 14)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err.Error())
        return
    }
    pdf.Cell(nil, "അതിവേഗ ഇംഗ്ലീഷ് നിഘണ്ടു ")
    pdf.WritePdf("hello.pdf")

}
```

Comment: You can't. That font requires OpenType features to display correctly, and gopdf does not support this.

Comment: [The issue](https://github.com/signintech/gopdf/issues/126) in the gopdf's tracker.

Comment: @usr2564301, which features, please?

Comment: @kostix: the lot. `akhn` for Akhands (a long list of them), `blwf` for a single Below-Base, `blws` for a number of Below-base subs, a couple of `half` and `haln` (Halant) forms, and lots of `pres` Pre-base, and `psts` Post-base subs and 3 `pstf` Post-Base forms (for language `mlym`, but only 2 for language `mlm2`). Note that some Indic languages require preprocessing before the actual shaping. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/script-development/malayalam for Microsoft's Uniscribe implementation.

Comment: @kostix: you're going to have a go at adding this to gopdf? At present it only supports kerning (I didn't check but I dare bet not even the `GPOS` flavour but only Ye Olde Style `kern`) so even basic features such standard `GSUB` substitutions (`onum`, `salt`, `smcp` etc.) and ligatures requires writing an entirely new shaper from scratch.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the observed behavior is by design for the current version of gopdf.

Comment: Does this mean that the preprocessing needs to be done by gopdf ? Currently why is the text messed up ? Is it because gopdf places the text as it is without any no preprocessing ? I was also wondering in this page, the html display of the Malayalam text is properly rendered - Is it because browser implements proper preprocessing?